# temporary table not returning result set in MySQL stored proc

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I have a stored proc which inserts rows from a view with ranks into a temporary table.

The temp table is created before I run a cursor loop that inserted values, and SELECT'ed after the loop is done.

However when I CALL medianMessagesPerWeek(); I get an "Error Code : 1329 No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed."

If I create the table as a MYISAM table I can manually select the table and confirm that data has been inserted but the stored proc will still give me nothing.

Am I missing something here?

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `yongopal_metrics`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `medianMessagesPerWeek`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `medianMessagesPerWeek`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE tempJoinWeek, tempActiveWeek, rank INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE joinWeek, activeWeek, memberNo, messages INT;
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM cohortMessagesPerMemberPerWeek;

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS medianMessagesPerWeek;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE medianMessagesPerWeek
    (
        joinWeek INT,
        activeWeek INT,
        memberNo INT,
        messages INT,
        rank INT
    ) ENGINE=MEMORY;    

    OPEN cur;

    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO joinWeek, activeWeek, memberNo, messages;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        IF tempJoinWeek = joinWeek AND tempActiveWeek = activeWeek THEN
            SET rank = rank + 1;
        ELSE
            SET tempJoinWeek = joinWeek;
            SET tempActiveWeek = activeWeek;
            SET rank = 1;
        END IF;
        INSERT INTO medianMessagesPerWeek VALUES (joinWeek, activeWeek, memberNo, messages, rank);
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur;

    SELECT * FROM medianMessagesPerWeek;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS medianMessagesPerWeek;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

**EDIT**

here is what cohortMessagesPerMemberPerWeek looks like

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `yongopal_metrics`$$

DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `cohortMessagesPerMemberPerWeek`$$

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `cohortMessagesPerMemberPerWeek` AS 
SELECT
  WEEK(`m`.`regDatetime`,0) AS `joinWeek`,
  WEEK(`cd`.`sendDate`,0) AS `activeWeek`,
  `m`.`memberNo` AS `memberNo`,
  COUNT(0)       AS `messages`
FROM (`yongopal`.`chatData` `cd`
   JOIN `yongopal`.`members` `m`
     ON ((`cd`.`sender` = `m`.`memberNo`)))
GROUP BY WEEK(`m`.`regDatetime`,0),WEEK(`cd`.`sendDate`,0),`m`.`memberNo`
ORDER BY WEEK(`m`.`regDatetime`,0),WEEK(`cd`.`sendDate`,0)$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're missing a [`not found` handler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare-handler.html) for your `cur` cursor. This is necessary to set your `done` boolean to true when the `fetch` statement no longer returns any rows (and hence you have reached the end of the dataset returned by the cursor declaration).

Give this a try:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `yongopal_metrics`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `medianMessagesPerWeek`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `medianMessagesPerWeek`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE tempJoinWeek, tempActiveWeek, rank INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE joinWeek, activeWeek, memberNo, messages INT;
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM cohortMessagesPerMemberPerWeek;

    declare continue handler for not found set done := true; 

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS medianMessagesPerWeek;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE medianMessagesPerWeek
    (
        joinWeek INT,
        activeWeek INT,
        memberNo INT,
        messages INT,
        rank INT
    ) ENGINE=MEMORY;    

    OPEN cur;

    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO joinWeek, activeWeek, memberNo, messages;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        IF tempJoinWeek = joinWeek AND tempActiveWeek = activeWeek THEN
            SET rank = rank + 1;
        ELSE
            SET tempJoinWeek = joinWeek;
            SET tempActiveWeek = activeWeek;
            SET rank = 1;
        END IF;
        INSERT INTO medianMessagesPerWeek VALUES (joinWeek, activeWeek, memberNo, messages, rank);
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur;

    SELECT * FROM medianMessagesPerWeek;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS medianMessagesPerWeek;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: wow, that did the trick! What exactly does declaring "not found" do?

Comment: I'm guessing that if that's not declared, the stored proc will just end after the cursor is finished looping?

Comment: Yes. Sort of. If you're missing the 'not found' handler then the proc will treat a 'no data found' state (i.e. the state when there is no data left to fetch from the cursor) as an error. Adding the handler tells the proc "if you get a 'no data found' state don't throw an error - just set my `done` boolean to true instead". Have a quick read of the link I posted in my answer since it'll be able to explain it better than I can! Glad it helped.